# How to convert NSDictionary to NSString which contains json of NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, ios6

How to convert `NSDictionary` to `NSString` which contains `JSON` of `NSDictionary` ?
I have tried like but without success

```
//parameters is NSDictionary
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters
                                                       options:0
                                                         error:&error];
```

Comment: What's the exact problem? Do you want to know how to make an NSString from an NSData?

Answer (score 5):

if jsonData is `NSDictionary`

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"json data is %@", jsonData];
```

OR if jsonData is  `NSData`

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Comment: You sure about this? NSData's description isn't exactly usable in most cases.

Comment: I am sure these are the ways to go!

Comment: Nice edit. Initially I would think jsonData referred to OP's variable, which is an NSData. But you did clarify what you meant. Although just printing an NSDictionary doesn't output JSON, it is still useful

Comment: Thanks for noticing, I should have clarified even once writing the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to inspect it, you can create a `NSString`:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But if you're writing it to a file or sending it to a server, you can just use your `NSData`. The above construct is useful for examining the value for debugging purposes.